# Multiple ID's in Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have multiple data tables with different ID tags and I'm trying to get the JavaScript file to apply the style if multiple ID's exist.

Here is what I have that is not working:

```
$(function() {
  $("[id*=tblAccount") || ("[id *= tblCustomer") || ("[id *= tblContact").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "dom": 'lBfrtip',
    "buttons": ['excel', 'print', 'pdfHtml5']
  });
})
```

Comment: You should begin by looking at the number/position of your parentheses: `$("[id*=tblAccount") ||` is not right, for example.

Comment: why not just use a class? after all that is what they are for - styling similar components with the same styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the selectors in a single call to jQuery using the CSS selector `,` operator:

```
$("[id*=tblAccount], [id *= tblCustomer], [id *= tblContact]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
```

(Also note that I added the missing `]` characters.)